# Determining whether a folder view is currently being filtered

Tags: c++, winapi, com, explorer

Is there a way to determine whether Explorer's current active folder view is being filtered by property (using the column drop-down menus)?  I've looked through the standard interfaces like `IFolderView`, `IFolderView2`, etc., and some of the filter-related interfaces as well, but I can't seem to find this.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not documented: https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/shell/shell32/api/filtercondition/create.htm good luck.

Comment: Could you share your use case? Like why do you need to determine if there is a filter applied or which property are you interested in?